# How to configure Spring Data to use Postgres with Hibernate without XML?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, postgresql, spring-data

I have the following application configuration for Spring Data.

```java
@Configuration
public class PluginConfig {
  @Bean
  public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource driver = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    driver.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
    driver.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql:activitydb");
    driver.setUsername("activityman");
    driver.setPassword("activitymanpasses");
    return driver;
  }

  @Bean
  public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    vendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.POSTGRESQL);
    vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);

    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    factory.setPackagesToScan(getClass().getPackage().getName());
    factory.setDataSource(dataSource());

    return factory;
  }

  @Bean
  @Autowired
  public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());

    return txManager;
  }
}
```

When I run a test case using `new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(PluginConfig.class)`, an exception is thrown saying that the database address is invalid. I wonder why?

```
StackTrace:

2015-09-29 17:15:50,535  WARN rg.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl: 204 - HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : invalid database address: jdbc:postgresql:activitydb
2015-09-29 17:15:50,658 ERROR            org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate: 226 - HHH000319: Could not get database metadata
java.sql.SQLException: invalid database address: jdbc:postgresql:activitydb
    at org.sqlite.JDBC.createConnection(JDBC.java:111) ~[sqlite-jdbc-3.8.7.jar:na]
    at org.sqlite.JDBC.connect(JDBC.java:88) ~[sqlite-jdbc-3.8.7.jar:na]
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:153) ~[spring-jdbc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:144) ~[spring-jdbc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:155) ~[spring-jdbc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:120) ~[spring-jdbc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:139) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.9.Final.jar:4.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.prepare(SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.java:51) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.9.Final.jar:4.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:219) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.9.Final.jar:4.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:203) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.9.Final.jar:4.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:522) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.9.Final.jar:4.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1859) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.9.Final.jar:4.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:857) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.9.Final.jar:4.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.9.Final.jar:4.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:425) [hibernate-core-4.3.9.Final.jar:4.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:849) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.9.Final.jar:4.3.9.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) [spring-orm-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343) [spring-orm-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318) [spring-orm-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:956) [spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:747) [spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480) [spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:84) [spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at np.com.rts.qms.plugin.reporting.test.DatabaseTestcase.testDatabaseConnection(DatabaseTestcase.java:18) [test-classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:78) [junit-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:212) [junit-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:68) [junit-rt.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140) [idea_rt.jar:na]
2015-09-29 17:15:50,664 ERROR            org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate: 272 - HHH000299: Could not complete schema update
java.sql.SQLException: invalid database address: jdbc:postgresql:activitydb
    at org.sqlite.JDBC.createConnection(JDBC.java:111) ~[sqlite-jdbc-3.8.7.jar:na]
    at org.sqlite.JDBC.connect(JDBC.java:88) ~[sqlite-jdbc-3.8.7.jar:na]
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:153) ~[spring-jdbc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:144) ~[spring-jdbc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:155) ~[spring-jdbc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:120) ~[spring-jdbc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:139) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.9.Final.jar:4.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.prepare(SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.java:51) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.9.Final.jar:4.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:219) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.9.Final.jar:4.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:203) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.9.Final.jar:4.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:522) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.9.Final.jar:4.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1859) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.9.Final.jar:4.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:857) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.9.Final.jar:4.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.9.Final.jar:4.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:425) [hibernate-core-4.3.9.Final.jar:4.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:849) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.9.Final.jar:4.3.9.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) [spring-orm-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343) [spring-orm-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318) [spring-orm-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:956) [spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:747) [spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480) [spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:84) [spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at np.com.rts.qms.plugin.reporting.test.DatabaseTestcase.testDatabaseConnection(DatabaseTestcase.java:18) [test-classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:78) [junit-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:212) [junit-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:68) [junit-rt.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140) [idea_rt.jar:na]
```

I see that it is trying to use SQLite, which completely weirds me out! I am simply trying to configure Hibernate to use Postgres database. Is it the dataSource() method that has gone wrong?

**UPDATE:
There was an SQLite driver dependency in the project, which when removed, solved the issue. But I wonder if this is by design, or a real issue?**

Comment: Is PostgreSQL driver in test classpath ?

Comment: It seems that you also have a SQLite JDBC driver on the classpath which intercepts the URL and throws an error (because it doesn't understand it). Remove the SQLite jar file from your project

Comment: @SergeBallesta, yes it is

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, you were right, I removed the dependency on SQLite and it worked. Isn't this a weird thing to happen since I have explicitly specified the driver to use?

Answer (score 16):

I think the database url format should be:

```
jdbc:postgresql://HOST:PORT/activitydb
```

I see that your database url is using the default for host:port which would be localhost:5432 if you database is not on local host it could be the issue.

Others have mentioned that you must have sqllite on the classpath and Spring is trying to auto configure it. (So remove it if this is not your intention)

I will offer the following configuration alternative to basic Postgres configuration. It allows Spring to auto configure a few more things and is a little less verbose.

With an application.properties file like this:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://HOST:PORT/activitydb
spring.datasource.username=activityman
spring.datasource.password=activitymanpasses
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
```

And a PluginConfig like this:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.activityman.db")
@EntityScan(basePackages = "com.activityman.domain")
public class DataConfiguration { 
}
```

You can set up a repository like this:

```
@Repository
@Qualifier(value = "userRepository")
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {
    public User findByUsername(String username);
    public User findByEmail(String email);
}
```

You could then let Spring configure things and then have access to your repository like so:

```
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(final String email)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        com.activityman.domain.User user = userRepository.findByEmail(email);
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = buildUserAuthority(user.getRoles());

        return buildUserForAuthentication(user, authorities);

    }

 // omitted for brevity
```

Comment: `jdbc:postgresql:activitydb` is valid: https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/94/connect.html

Comment: Thanks. I hadn't used that short cut syntax before!

Comment: @MichaelKowalski, the problem was fixed by removing dependency on SQLite. And thanks for the alternate config. :)

Comment: @MichaelKowalski the above example uses a dialect PostgreSQLDialect that is deprecated. I suggest to update this to PostgreSQL10Dialect

Answer (score 5):

That's the basic postgres configuraiton for datasource

```
@Bean
DataSource dataSource() {
    BasicDataSource dataSourceConfig = new BasicDataSource();
    dataSourceConfig.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");

    dataSourceConfig.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/databasename");
    dataSourceConfig.setUsername("username");
    dataSourceConfig.setValidationQuery("SELECT 1");
    dataSourceConfig.setPassword("password");

    return dataSourceConfig;
}
```

And hibernate in case you need it

```
private static final String[] ENTITY_PACKAGES = {
        "com.applicationname.security.domain",
        "com.applicationname.audit.domain"
};

@Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(ENTITY_PACKAGES);

    Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();

    //Configures the used database dialect. This allows Hibernate to create SQL
    //that is optimized for the used database.
    jpaProperties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT, "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect");

    //Specifies the action that is invoked to the database when the Hibernate
    //SessionFactory is created or closed.
    jpaProperties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO, "none");

    //Configures the naming strategy that is used when Hibernate creates
    //new database objects and schema elements
    //jpaProperties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_NAMING_STRATEGY, env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_NAMING_STRATEGY));

    //If the value of this property is true, Hibernate writes all SQL
    //statements to the console.
    jpaProperties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL, "true");

    //If the value of this property is true, Hibernate will use prettyprint
    //when it writes SQL to the console.
    jpaProperties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_FORMAT_SQL, "true");

    entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);

    return entityManagerFactoryBean;
}
```