# Cannot connect Spring Boot to remote PostgreSQL server

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate

I'm trying to connect my Spring Boot application to a remote PostgreSQL server database.

My application.properties file has the following:

```
server.port=8102
spring.jpa.database=POSTGRESQL
spring.datasource.platform=postgres
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql:192.168.4.33:5432/postgres
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=secretpassword
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
logging.level.org.springframework.web=debug
logging.level.org.hibernate=debug
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
```

However, when I try to run my app, it comes out with the following error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
```

I'm not sure why Spring Boot is trying to use localhost still as I'm sure I've specifically asked it to use the IP address instead.

Comment: try `application.properties` instead of `Application.properties`.

Comment: Apologies @tgdavies it is ```application.properties``` instead of ```Application.properties```. I've adjusted OP.

Comment: please have a look here what the url format should be like you are missing the double forward slashes https://stackoverflow.com/a/32843504/1840146

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have connection refuse.please make sure your database up and correct username and pass.or network is ok.

jdbc:postgresql://HOST:PORT/activitydb

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the URL is correct.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql:192.168.4.33:5432/postgres
```

You should use `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://192.168.4.33:5432/postgres`

if it doesn't work then I suggest looking at your firewall or checking if that port is open on the server.